# How do I design a backend API with a different query range?

Tags: design, design-patterns, api-design, front-end, backend

If I have a blog system, there is now a query that is given a range and then gets the number of new blogs in that range. The range may be：

1. one day
2. one week
3. a month
4. six months
5. a year

How do I design the backend API? Is the design of five independent API, or the design of an API to pass five different enum values on behalf of the situation, or the design of one API that receives a  DateTime list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GET /recent?range=1m
```

or

```
GET /posts?recent=1m
```

All of your range queries are essentially the same query, but they are parametrized by the time window. That is a good fit for query parameters in the URI.

How this range is specified depends entirely on your use cases, e.g. you might want to allow a specific set of durations (`1d 1w 1m 6m 1y` and so on), or allow arbitrary durations to be constructed (e.g. `28d`), or allow an explicit start date, possibly with an end date: `/posts?from=2017-10-18&to=now`.